# Change event is not working in this scenario

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text1</span><input type='text'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text3</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='radio'><span>None of all</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is my jQuery code..

```
$(':checkbox').live('change',function()
            {
                $(':radio').prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
            });
$(':radio').live('change',function()
            {
                $(':checkbox').prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
            });

$('table :text').live('keyup', function() {
var um = $(this).closest('td').find('input');
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    um.prop('checked', true);
}
else {
    um.prop('checked', false);
}
});
```

What the above code will do is

```
 1. Checkboxes and Radio button are mutually exclusive
 2. On change of a textbox automatically the checkbox inside its parent will checked/unchecked.
```

But

**My concern is When i first click radio button, Then if i change text in textbox the checkbox will be checked but the radio button remains unchecked..** Why this is happening..   Please help me on this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same Problem with an autocomplete Plugin where a selection of that changed the text element but did not trigger the change event. You could add a

```
um.trigger("change");
```

after your if/else

Comment: but you said either checkbox or radio button are checked. not both.. but you select radio button and uncheck the checked check box and see the results.

Comment: The change event seems to be only fired if the user does anything himself, and as you change the value from your script it does not. I see it the same way as you do and think that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to fire a change event when changing that checkbox's state:

```
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
    um.prop('checked', true);
}else{
    um.prop('checked', false);
}
um.change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead if Change use Click

```
$(':checkbox').live('change',function()  {
```

hope it will works fine for you